Show Google Search results in Images rather than All tab from c#
I would like to run Google Search using the default browser from a C# program using a specified search string. I can do this via the command
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = url, UseShellExecute = true });

where URL is the URI -converted search string and is something like:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Med-L+Mamm:+Red+Necked+Wallaby

This shows the results of the Google search in the All tab.
How can make Google shows the results in the Images tab?

google.com/images?btnG=1&pws=0&q=SimonKravis

This question is similar to: Format for a url that goes to Google image search?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add tbm=isch to the end of the URL, so the new URL is:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Med-L+Mamm:+Red+Necked+Wallaby&tbm=isch

For all tbm possible values, see:
https://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-advanced-power-search-url-request-parameters/
